# How to free up multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawValue and multiprocessing.sharedctypes.RawArray?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing, shared-memory

In Python 3.8 I have a few shared memory values like these:

```
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import RawArray, RawValue

...

sm_best_score_gpu_id = RawValue(ctypes.c_double, -1)
sm_positions = RawArray(ctypes.c_int32, genome_positions)
```

This needs to be reallocated every once in a while. If I just repeat these operations in a loop, will this memory be automatically freed when the original variables are garbage collected?

I look through the ctypes docs but didn't find anything related to free up memory.

How can I free up this memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fine. The garbage collection may not occur immediately. On non-CPython interpreters like PyPy, Jython, etc., all collection is non-deterministic. On CPython (the "reference" interpreter, which is, rather appropriately, reference-counted), collection is deterministic when no reference cycles are involved, but if a reference cycle forms (which can happen accidentally in weird cases like raised exceptions containing frames in their tracebacks), and one of these objects is attached to something in the cycle, it won't be cleaned up until the cycle itself is collected, which occurs at an unspecified future time (and might not occur at all if the cycle collector is disabled with `gc.disable()`, or outstanding objects are frozen with `gc.freeze()`).

As long as "cleaned eventually" is fine, and you're not interfering with the cyclic garbage collector, cleanup will happen eventually (the underlying type [uses a finalizer to ensure the memory is freed back to the shared heap it came from](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/multiprocessing/heap.py#L322)).

Comment: Coming from C / C++ world I was worried about creating a memory leak. But if it gets cleaned eventually, then it's OK. Thanks a lot!